# AngularJS 1.5 - Iterate and set child components' property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a parent component that creates "n" child components within an ng-repeat. Each child component has an accordion element (from ui-bootstrap directives) in its template.
 From the parent component I would like to collapse or expand all accordions using a link in the parent component level. Each child accordion can be expanded/collapsed individually setting the local `vm.isAccordionExpanded` variable.
I am planning to use `$scope.$broadcast()` form the parent to notify the children, each of them will intercept the events with `$scope.$on()` and set a local boolean variable `vm.isAccordionExpanded` to open/close the accordion respectively.

Parent component template:

```
<span id="accordionListCommands" ng-if="vm.pastVisits.totalResults > 0">
    <span  id="collapseAllAccordion">
        <a ng-click="vm.collapseAll()" href="">
          <i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </span>
    <span  id="expandAllAccordion">
        <a ng-click="vm.expandAll()" href=""> 
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </span>
</span>

<div ng-repeat="visitItem in vm.pastVisits.data">
    <visits-list-component visit="visitItem"></visits-list-component>
</div>
```

Parent component js file:

```
$scope.$on('collapse-all-accordion', function () {
    vm.isAccordionExpanded = false;
});

$scope.$on('expand-all-accordion', function () {
    vm.isAccordionExpanded = true;
});
```

Child template:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="false">
    <div uib-accordion-group is-open="vm.isAccordionExpanded">

//Rest of the template
```

Is there a better or more performant way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like a good way. Always use `track by` in ng-repeat to increase performance. Also, you could use `is-open="vm.isAccordionExpanded || allExpanded"`, and have the latter variable set to true to expand all.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about track bz Index, I edited the answer to show how I set the vm.isAccordionExpanded variable when the events are triggered. I think the logic is enough without adding allExpanded variable, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes your logic works great, it is just that instead of setting up multiple event listeners it will only do it during the digest cycle. Not sure about how much of performance you'll gain. Anyways your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing this is not right and its not the angular way to write it.
Instead use one way data binding or two way data binging:

```
bindings: {
  visit: '<' // or ('=') respectivly
}
```

and then implement your collapseAll function like follows:

```
angular.forEach( vm.pastVisits.data,function(visitItem) { 
  visitItem.isAccordionExpanded = false;
});
```

then in the visit component you can write:

```
vm.$onChanges = function() {
 if(changes.visit) {
   vm.isAccordionExpanded = changes.visit.currentValue.isAccordionExpanded;
 }

}
```

or even better without having to put $onChanges listener :

```
<uib-accordion close-others="false">
<div uib-accordion-group is-open="vm.visit.isAccordionExpanded">
```

Comment: Your approach has the benefit of not using events, but personally I do not like it (not saying that is not right), as you are adding a property (isAccordionExpanded) completely extraneous to the visit model. I am planning to have the child component using "require" to get the isAccordionExpanded flag from the parent component. There is a blog post from Todd Motto about this approach, that seems to be the "angular way"

Comment: Ok so about the "require" it is a bad practice to couple your components. Its always best if you components are as decoupled as possible. You should only use "require" if the component can not exist without the context of a parent. In this case your child component is a simple accordion that can exist alone and does not have any interaction with the other components, so you should not use require. As for Todd motto you can read his style guide https://toddmotto.com/rewriting-angular-styleguide-angular-2, there you see using event system is deprecated .

Comment: As for the event system it was never meant to be used in order to update data in such a way. For this you have data bindings, and as of angular 2 one way data binding with a binding method for "on-update" is replacing 2 way data binding. In you case however you don't need an update binding function or 2 way data bindign because your child component is not updating the parent. And as last thing about isAccordionExpanded, it should exist there in the first place. So the cleanest way and the least code is  just makign one way data bidning and using $ctrl.visit.isAccordionExpanded

Comment: Thanks for the link to the new styleguide, I missed that post. At the end I refactored my code and it is easier now by using an extra variable as suggested.

Comment: yeah i will update my answer, extra binding varialbe is best